# access dynamic json data using angularjs

Tags: json, angularjs

Take a look at my json here :

```
{
"cartItems": {
    "743919183": {
        "code": "743919183",
        "title": "Responsive Website Package",
        "url_image": "http://www.domain.com/someimage.jpg",
    }
}
}
```

I want to display the value of `url_image`, but hard to pass the objet after `cartItems`. FYI, that number `743919183` is dynamic, I cannot hard coded it in my script. That will be a problem when the value is change.

how do i do it in angularjs?

my progress so far :

```
<div class="list">
<a class="item item-thumbnail-left" ng-repeat="cart in viewCartItem" href="#">
  <span ng-repeat="item in cart">
  <img ng-repeat="obj in item" ng-src="{{obj.url_image}}">
  </span>
</a>
```

it will display the image , but it turn out messing with templates stylesheet. How do i do it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this code:

```
$.each(chart.cartItems, function(key, value) {
  console.log(value);
  console.log(value.code)
  console.log(value.title)
  console.log(value.url_image)
});
```